# Material Design Lite - Search bar in Nav header

Tags: css, material-design-lite

Ok so the issue is that when I load this - https://codepen.io/russellharrower/pen/aZmJya You will notice that the right side is not the same as the left. I am wondering how I would go about to correct this please.

I need the right padding to be like the left.

```
        <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
            <!-- Title -->
            <span class="mdl-layout-title">IPET</span></span>
            <!-- Add spacer, to align navigation to the right -->
            <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
            <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--expandable mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-textfield--align-right">
                <label class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon" for="fixed-header-drawer-exp">
                    <i class="material-icons">search</i>
                </label>
                <div class="mdl-textfield__expandable-holder">
                    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" name="sample" id="fixed-header-drawer-exp" />
                </div>

        <button id="demo-menu-lower-right"
                class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--icon">
          <i class="material-icons">chat</i>
        </button>
        <ul class="mdl-menu mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-menu--bottom-right"
            for="demo-menu-lower-right">
          <li class="mdl-menu__item">Some Action</li>
          <li class="mdl-menu__item">Another Action</li>
          <li disabled class="mdl-menu__item">Disabled Action</li>
          <li class="mdl-menu__item">Yet Another Action</li>
        </ul>
            </div>

        </div>

    </header>
```

Comment: Your question is currently unclear, can you clarify? Do you want the two sides to look the same, function the same, or what exactly?

Comment: @ghost_dad I need the right to have the same padding as left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, looks like it should be as simple as updating the styling on the `.mdl-layout__header-row` element. Like so:

```
.mdl-layout__header-row {
  padding: 0 80px 0 80px;
}
```

Adjust the padding, as needed. Edited, as I misread and made the left same as right rather than other way around. Here's an updated Codepen:

https://codepen.io/thecox/pen/ezdveV